# in eclipse cdt, how to build target other than the first one

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I am quite newbie in using eclipse cdt. I have a makefile project, and have more than two targets in my Makefile. Say the Makefile is as follows,

```
all: 
 ...
t1:
 ...
t2:
 ...
```

it's easy to make CDT build target 'all'. However, how can I build targets other than the first one, like t1 and t2? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In eclipse, go to:

Window > Show View > Make Target

In the view that opens up, right click your project, click on "New".

Give your target a name, say "T1". Uncheck the "same as the target name" and put the "Make Target" value to t1.
Same for t2.

The next time you want to build your targets, look at the Make Target view that you opened, and double click the target you want.